# Json Deserialize Date not working

Tags: java, json, date

In Json list i'm getting such a date: "lastModifiedDate":1459202400000". Serialize and Deserialize class they seem to be ok.

Entity class:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
@Data
@ToString
@Entity
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=JsonDateDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "LastModifiedDate", columnDefinition="DATETIME", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private java.util.Date lastModifiedDate;

}
```

Deserializer class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;

@Component
public class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(jsonParser.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JsonParseException("Could not parse date", jsonParser.getCurrentLocation(), e);
        }
    }
```

What's wrong?
    }

Comment: Looks like your `dateFormat` is not the format in which your data is coming.

Comment: Why it is marked as duplicated? In the other question there is nothing about JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You are not parsing the date correctly. Right now you receive a date in milliseconds, so you have first to create a date before formatting, i.e.:

```
dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(jsonParser.getText())));
```

Or if you just want to create the Date object from it, just skip the format part.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I also tried and still doesn't working. I added logger and in console but on the console nothing log. I changed desarialize to @JsonFormat and now works